# how to execute dot command of sqlite using C-APIs

Tags: c, linux, sqlite

I want to execute .dump file on my sqlite DB. I am using sqlite 3.7.17 version. I develop code to create DB and insert data into that DB using c-lang code. At run time of my code i want to execute .dump file using command ".dump DB.dump" which is not executed through API slite3_exec(). Please give me solution ...

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide some code ?

Comment: sqlite3_exec(pDB_in, (MXascii *)cpQuery_in, 0, 0, &acpErrMsg); I simply used this API to execute ".dump DB.dump" coz this API i used to execute "BEGIN TRANSACTION;" pDB_in indicate sqlite DB handle, cpQuery_in indicate ".dump DB.dump" query etc.

Comment: Sorry its not .dump Its ".read DB.dump" command i m sorry

Answer (score 4):

The dot commands are not SQLite statements; they are special commands implemented by the `sqlite3` command-line tool.

Run the `sqlite3` tool from your program (execute `sqlite3 my.db .dump`), or copy the code from SQLite's `shell.c`.